# React.js - ul tag height won't cover the whole screen of browser

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making a simple navbar where if I click on hamburger icon, it should open my side nav which covers full width and height of screen. However, for some reason, the height of the side nav does not cover the whole screen.

Navbar code :

```
const NavBar = () => {
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true)
    return (
        <>
            <div className='navWrap flex items-center justify-between m-7'>
                <img className='w-[3em]' src={Logo} alt="" />

                <ul className='hidden xl:flex gap-3'>
                    <li><a href="/">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Notes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div onClick={() => setFlag(!flag)} className='xl:hidden cursor-pointer text-2xl z-50'>
                    {flag ? <AiOutlineMenu />
                        : <AiOutlineClose />}
                </div>

                <ul className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen bg-slate-400'>
                    <li><a href="/">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Notes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I have tried making the body height 100% but it's still not covering the full screen. I'm using Tailwind by the way.

Comment: `h-screen` should make full screen, can you make minimal reproducible example ?